# Regarding Print options in web application 

Tags: java, spring

I want to give print options in our web application..We are using technologies like spring 3.0,hibernate3.0 and mysql database..What i want is single file ,multiple file print options..When i select check box perticular file  after click print button it should go to the  printer...Please give some example related to this print options using technologies like Spring,hibernate and mysql database..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can go with this, so I'll give you some options to consider:

- If you don't care too much about the pixel-perfect formatting, the easiest way is to display a new html document with all the files combined and specify `@media print` in your CSS for that document. Launch the printer dialog for that document using `window.print()`.
- If formatting is very important you may consider rendering a PDF document. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) is a good choice since you're using a Java stack.
- If you are in an enterprise environment and know which printers a user can access then you can send Postscript or PDF commands directly to the printer. This is probably the most work but also the most transparent to the user since it can be automated completely.